# Access violation while writing to position in an __asm XorBlock function?

Tags: c++, assembly, xor

0xC0000005: Access violation while writing to position 0x00A85E00 , thats the exception i get while trying to run following code :

```
static class ClassName {
public:
 static void function() {

    //doSomething       


 }
 static void functionStub() {
    __asm _emit 0xCC
    __asm _emit 0xCC
    __asm _emit 0xCC
    __asm _emit 0xCC
 }
};


DWORD randomDWORD() {  
 random_device generator;  
 uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 255);  
 return DWORD(distribution(generator));  
}

void XorBlock(DWORD dwStartAddress, DWORD dwSize , DWORD key){  
__asm {  
    push eax  
    push ecx  
    mov ecx, dwStartAddress            
    add ecx, dwSize                   
    mov eax, dwStartAddress          
    mov ebx, key  
    crypt_loop :                           
    xor byte ptr ds : [eax], bl    <------exeption*  
        inc eax                          
        cmp eax, ecx                       
        jl crypt_loop;                       
    pop ecx  
    pop eax  
 }  
}  

int GetFuncSize(void *funcaddress){  
 int length = 0;  
 for (length = 0; *((UINT32 *)(&((unsigned char *)funcaddress)[length])) != 0xCCCCCCCC; ++length);  
 return length;  
}
int main(){  
 DWORD dwKey = randomDWORD();  
 auto functionstart = ClassName::function;  
 DWORD dwFunctionSize = GetFuncSize(&ClassName::function);  
 XorBlock((DWORD)functionstart, dwFunctionSize, dwKey); <---exception  
}
```

0x00A85E00 is dwStartAddress btw .. how can i fix this ? :/  would apreciate if someone can help me with my existing code or can show me an better alternative , maybe with already existing functions to xor a function at runtime.

thank u for your help.

greetings

slauko

Comment: The code section is read only. You need to make it writable, e.g. using [VirtualProtect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898.aspx). PS: you don't need assembly to xor a block of memory.

Comment: thank you , helped me to get this to work :)

Comment: There is also no guarantee about the order the linker will place the functions in memory. Or that the it will not discard a function that is never called, like `functionStub`.

Comment: i have disabled optimization at linker , so it should be fine